# Making Images move left to right out of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to make my top and bottom image to move out of the screen, and when they are out of the screen; my image logo appears. This was working perfectly but when I constrained my images they did the opposite.

So Instead of moving out of the screen, they come from outside the screen and move into the screen.

This is my code, thanks in advance.

```
func dismissImages(){
        imageLogo.isHidden = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 17) {
            //self.topImage.frame.origin.x
            self.topImage.center.x -= 400

        }


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 17, animations: {
            self.bottomImage.center.x += 400
        }) { (sucess) in
            if sucess {
                self.imageLogo.isHidden = false
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout ? If so, you should animate the constraint instead of your control frame.

Comment: As @GIJOW mentioned, if you are using autolayout, you should assume that you can't control bounds / center / frame anymore and they will reset every time your view constraints are applied (as you've noticed, you can still change these properties between applications). Again, as was mentioned above, you can animate constraints although it can be a little verbose. Alternatively, you can change the transform property which would look something like ... self.topImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -400, y: 0)

Comment: Just keep in mind that using frame based layouts could make new iPhone/iPad releases much more of a headache than using constraints with Adaptive Layouts.

Answer (score 1):

I Figured it out. I called my animation function before I called my constraints functions. I worked perfectly when I put mu animation function in ViewDidAppear. That way the animations will only occur when the view appears and constraints are set.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest animating the layer instead of the view itself

```
func dismissImages(){
    imageLogo.isHidden = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 17) {
        self.topImage.layer.frame.origin.x -= self.view.frame.width
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 17, animations: {
        self.bottomImage.layer.frame.origin.x += self.view.frame.width
    }) { guard $0 else { return }
        self.imageLogo.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't it lead to broken constraints ? Just wondering, never tried

Comment: nope, because you're not moving the view instead the layer

Comment: For a few years now Apple has discouraged the use of frames/layers for layouts, mainly because when new iPhones/iPads are available (iPhone 6/6+, iPhone X, etc.) there is a good chance your layout will break. Rather they recommend using Auto Layout (i.e. constraints) to create Adaptive layouts that adapt to various screen sizes.

See: [Auto Layout Versus Frame-Based Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW4)

Comment: @TenaciousJay they didn't mention "layer" not even once plus I ran a test with constraints on the views before posting my answer. here are some stuff that I follow [Auto Layout Techniques in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/412/) [Advanced Animations with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/230)

Answer (score 0):

Setup an NSLayoutConstraint for each image and animate the constant for that constraint.

```
// SETUP INITIAL POSITION
let topImageHorizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: topImage, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) // Note: Change the constant from 0 to whatever you need it to be initially.

// ACTIVATE CONSTRAINT
topImageHorizontalConstraint.isActive = true

// ANIMATE THE CONSTANT ON THE CONSTRAINT
// Note: This part will be in dismissImages().
UIView.animate(withDuration: 17, animations: {
    topImageHorizontalConstraint.constant -= 400                
},
completion: { (animationFinished: Bool) in
    if animationFinished {
            // Show logo or whatever
    }
})
```

As of iOS 9+ you can use NSLayoutAnchor to create the constraints and simplify things a bit.

```
// SETUP INITIAL POSITION
let topImageHorizontalConstraint = topImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)

// ACTIVATE CONSTRAINT
topImageHorizontalConstraint.isActive = true

// ANIMATE THE CONSTANT ON THE CONSTRAINT
// Note: This part will be in dismissImages().
UIView.animate(withDuration: 17, animations: {
    topImageHorizontalConstraint.constant -= 400                
},
completion: { (animationFinished: Bool) in
    if animationFinished {
            // Show logo or whatever
    }
})
```

I like anchors because it seems easier to visualize the relationship but it's pretty similar in this case.

**Note:** You'll need to have variables for your constraints outside of dismissImages(). Then create the constraints in init() or viewDidLoad() or somewhere initially, then call dismissImages() to animate the change.

Comment: Your answer is good but somehow I feel that’s too much work for something you’re trying to hide